# Using Serilog Slack Sink Via XML Configuration

Tags: c#, logging, slack-api, serilog

1. Is it possible to configure [Slack sink](https://github.com/mgibas/serilog-sinks-slack) using serilog [XML configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings)?
2. Is any sink configurable via code is also configurable via XML or it has to explicitly support it?

Comment: On (2), yes, 99% of sinks "just work" with XML configuration. To generate the XML from the code automatically in Visual Studio, check out https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer. Cheers!

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt WOW! amazing. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Incase anybody encounters this, I was able to do it:

```
<add key="serilog:using:Slack" value="Serilog.Sinks.Slack" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Slack.webhookUrl" value="https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Slack.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Error"/>
```